# VS 2015 Gulp Failed to load message

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, gulp

I'm just getting started with gulp in a .NET 4.6 project and I'm getting the error "Failed to load" in task runner explorer. My gulpfile is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var print = require('gulp-print');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    console.log('Hello Gulp!');
});

gulp.task('css-task', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('./index.html');

    var customCssStream = gulp.src(['./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css']);

    return target
        .pipe(inject(customCssStream.pipe(print())
        .pipe(concat('appStyles.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./Content/css')), { name: 'styles' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

});
```

And the error is:

> gulp-inject/src/inject/index.js:127 startTag, ^ SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token , at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16) at
>   Module._compile (module.js:443:25) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:478:10) at Module.load (module.js:355:32) at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12) at Module.require
>   (module.js:365:17) at require (module.js:384:17) at Object.
>   (.../node_modules/gulp-inject/index.js:4:28) at Module._compile
>   (module.js:460:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)

I was able to get the "Hello Gulp!" task to run, but once I add gulp-inject I see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was related to the version of node.js that Visual Studio 2015 installed not being compatible with node-inject module. After I installed version 4.4.2 of [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and pointed visual studio at it as described [here](http://ryanhayes.net/synchronize-node-js-install-version-with-visual-studio-2015/) it now compiles.